# Overlap ranges in single dataframe

Tags: r

I am looking to flag rows in my df that have overlapping ranges (looking to create the Overlap Column) based a range of numeric variables (Min,Max), which I could transform into integer if necessary:

```
Class    Min  Max
    A    100  200
    A    120  205
    A    210  310
    A    500  630
    A    510  530
    A    705  800
```

Transform into:

```
Class    Min  Max  Overlap
    A    100  200        1
    A    120  205        1
    A    210  310        0
    A    500  630        1
    A    510  530        1
    A    705  800        0
```

I have tried IRanges without much success - any ideas?

Comment: You want to pairwise test all intervals for overlaps? Are you sure you need this?

Comment: I think the logic could work like this: `overlap = [ (minVal > any other min) AND ( minVal < maxVal )  ] OR [ (maxVal < any other max) AND ( maxVal > minVal )  ] ` Right?

Comment: With `IRanges`, it seems you just need `countOverlaps(IRanges(dat$Min, dat$Max)) - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outer` is my function of choice for doing pairwise comparisons fast. You can create the pairwise comparison of the interval endpoints using `outer` and then combine the comparisons in any way you want. In this case I check if the two rules required for an overlap hold true simultaneously.

```
library(dplyr)

df_foo = read.table(
textConnection("Class    Min  Max
A    100  200
A    120  205
A    210  310
A    500  630
A    510  530
A    705  800"), header = TRUE
)

c = outer(df_foo$Max, df_foo$Min, ">")
d = outer(df_foo$Min, df_foo$Max, "<")

df_foo %>% 
  mutate(Overlap = apply(c & d, 1, sum) > 1 
)
```

Comment: This will probably get out of memory pretty quickly and what is `dplyr` and `apply` with a margin of `1` here for? What's wrong with just `df_foo$Overlap <- rowSums(c & d) > 1`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg As far as memory usage is concerned, I don't think you can do less than this, but that is for other answers to explore.

Comment: @DavidArenburg As for your other concerns, those are just semantics. There are no real implications of using either.

Comment: These are not just semantics. `apply` with a margin of `1` is much less efficient than `rowSums`. And loading unnecessary dependencies seem, well unnecessary

Comment: @DavidArenburg Unnecessary in the code that you are about to contribute, not in mine. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I find data.table very effective for doing overlaps, using `foverlaps`

```
 library(data.table)
```

Recreating the data:

```
dt <- data.table(Class = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
           Min = c(100, 120, 210, 500, 510, 705),
           Max = c(200, 205, 310, 630, 530, 800))
```

Keying the data.table, this is required for the function:

```
setkey(dt, Min, Max)
```

here we do `foverlaps` against itself, then filter, removing those rows which are overlapping with themselves. The number of rows are then counted grouped by `Min` and `Max`.

```
dt_overlaps <- foverlaps(dt, dt, type = "any")[Min != i.Min & Max != i.Max, .(Class, Overlap = .N), by = c("Min", "Max")]
```

Thanks to DavidArenburg

```
dt[dt_overlaps, Overlap := 1]
```

Results:

```
> dt
  Class Min Max Overlap
1     A 100 200       1
2     A 120 205       1
3     A 210 310      NA
4     A 500 630       1
5     A 510 530       1
6     A 705 800      NA
```

There is probably neater data.table code for this, but I'm learning as well.

Comment: If you want to do the join using `data.table`, you could do `dt[dt_overlaps, Overlap := 1] ; dt` which will modify `dt` in place. The problem with this solution though, that for big enough data OP will probably get out of memory pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df_foo%>%mutate(flag=coalesce(ifelse(Max>lead(Min),1,NA),ifelse(lag(Max)>Min,1,NA)))
  Class Min Max flag
1     A 100 200    1
2     A 120 205    1
3     A 210 310   NA
4     A 500 630    1
5     A 510 530    1
6     A 705 800   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) package for this, which is a specialized package for working with intervals. You can use `iv_count_overlaps()` to count the number of self-overlaps, and then filter that for any time you saw >1 overlap (you will always have at least 1 overlap because each interval will match itself).

```r
library(ivs)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(Class = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
             Min = c(100, 120, 210, 500, 510, 705),
             Max = c(200, 205, 310, 630, 530, 800))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Range = iv(Min, Max), .keep = "unused")

df %>%
  mutate(Overlap = iv_count_overlaps(Range, Range) > 1L)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   Class      Range Overlap
#>   <chr>  <iv<dbl>> <lgl>  
#> 1 A     [100, 200) TRUE   
#> 2 A     [120, 205) TRUE   
#> 3 A     [210, 310) FALSE  
#> 4 A     [500, 630) TRUE   
#> 5 A     [510, 530) TRUE   
#> 6 A     [705, 800) FALSE
```